# Ruby Command not return expected value

Tags: ruby, command

In my redhat 5 RoR, i have a command calling a jar to pull xml from another system.
irb:

```
2.1.5 :005 >  %x(java -jar ./GENTESTResult.jar -action=status -user="tester" -password="tester" -job_id="12324")
<?xml version="1.0"?><cliout action="status" request_id="1446456310693_54" >
<action_status>ERROR</action_status>
<action_status_detail>Given job not found.</action_status_detail><job id="12324"/>
</cliout>
 => "" 

2.1.5 :006 > %x(java -jar ./GENTESTResult.jar -action=status -user="tester" -password="tester" -job_id="5192782")
 => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><cliout action=\"status\" request_id=\"1446456368168_11\" >\n<action_status>SUCCESS</action_status><action_status_detail>Job has been processed successfully.</action_status_detail><job id=\"5192782\" status=\"Failed\" >\n...(stop paste)
```

the first job id "12324" is not exist. the second job id 5192782 is a valid id.
I don't have question on the job 5192782. 
But for job "12324", my ruby code

```
@lines = %x(java -jar ./GENTESTResult.jar -action=status -user="tester" -password="tester" -job_id="12324")
```

gave me empty string. but i really need the xml that from the result key part which is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><cliout action="status" request_id="1446456310693_54" >
    <action_status>ERROR</action_status>
    <action_status_detail>Given job not found.</action_status_detail><job id="12324"/>
    </cliout>
```

How can i get the string? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not catching the output because it's being printed on stderr.

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2012/10/18/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby.html is a comprehensive blog post about the subject, you might want to look at popen3 and popen2e in particular